# How to split string using regex to split between +,-,*,/ symbols?

Tags: ruby, regex

I need to tell Ruby in regex to `split` before and after the `+ - * /` symbols in my program.

**Examples:**

I need to turn `"1+12"` into `[1.0, "+", 12.0]`

and `"6/0.25"` into `[6.0, "/", 0.25]`

There could be cases like `"3/0.125"` but highly unlikely. If first two I listed above are satisfied it should be good.

On the Ruby docs, `"hi mom".split(%r{\s*}) #=> ["h", "i", "m", "o", "m"]`

I looked up a [cheat-sheet](https://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/) to try to understand `%r{\s*}`, and I know that the stuff inside `%r{}` such as `\s` are skipped and \s means white space in regex.

Comment: will there be case like `1.0+12`?

Comment: Yes! Thanks for pointing out that edge case. There will be instances such as `0.5*12`.

Comment: will there be cases like `1.46+12.4`? what will be its output?

Comment: There could be. This is a 24 game simulator, so if somebody does `6/0.25 = 24`, it could happen.

Comment: so you want the output for `1.46+12.4` to be `1.46+12.4` only

Comment: In what sense is `"1"` or `1.0` a two digit number?

Comment: @sawa I reworded the question to "How to split string using regex to split between +,-,*,/ symbols?". Thanks!

Comment: Would it not just be [+-*/]+ ?

Comment: @rykeeboy, Can you write out the whole method? I'm unclear to what you mean. Thanks.

Comment: Could there be cases like `-1+2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this could be useful:

```
"1.2+3.453".split('+').flat_map{|elem| [elem, "+"]}[0...-1]
# => ["1.2", "+", "3.453"]
"1.2+3.453".split('+').flat_map{|elem| [elem.to_f, "+"]}[0...-1]
# => [1.2, "+", 3.453]
```

Obviously this work only for `+`. But you can change the `split` `character`.

EDIT:

This version work for every operator

```
"1.2+3.453".split(%r{(\+|\-|\/|\*)}).map do |x|
    unless x =~ /(\+|\-|\/|\*)/ then x.to_f else x end
end
# => [1.2, "+", 3.453]
```

Comment: Hi David. Thanks for this. I don't know how to add conditionals inside the split. I need more than just additional symbol, such as `"6/0.25" => [ 6, "/", 0.25 ].

Comment: I guess I can just do conditionals such as `if string.includes?("+")`, run `.split('+').flat_map{|elem| [elem, "+"]}[0...-1]` and `if string.includes?("-")`, run `.split('-').flat_map{|elem| [elem, "-"]}[0...-1]`, but that's not DRY.

Comment: @KaMok i have edited the code to work for every operator

Comment: Nevermind it was actually pretty easy to understand. I figured it out after commenting sections of the code and seeing what it does. It'll still be good for the future visitors though!

Comment: Converting string representations of integers to floats could be a problem down the line. A small point: `'-'` need not be escaped if it is at the beginning of your list of or's. You can let [Regexp::union](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Regexp.html#method-c-union) look after the needed escaping: `/(#{Regexp.union("+*/-")})/ #=> /((?-mix:\+\*\/\-))/ `.

Comment: You could also use a character class: `%r{([-+*/])}`

Answer (score 2):

```
'1.0+23.7'.scan(/(((\d\.?)+)|[\+\-\*\/])/)
```

Comment: This matters because the array of characters you got is due to the split function operating even though there is no whitespace in a zero length match. On a one or more length match only splits will occur when there is a character in between.

Comment: Alternatively, you could acquire just the numeric values using .split(%r{\D+})

Comment: Edited to reflect your updated question. A match to either numeric or operator strings is a better function than split for your case.

Comment: Sorry I don't quite understand the match method, can you please write it out?

Comment: Hi, I ran your updated code in the irb and I got this: `/((\d+\.?)+|[\+\-\*\/])/.match('1+23.7').to_a
=> ["1", "1", "1"]`

Answer (score 2):

instead of splitting, *match* with capture groups to parse your inputs:

```
(?<operand1>(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?)|(?:\.\d+))\s*(?<operator>[+\/*-])\s*(?<operand2>(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?)|(?:\.\d+))
```

explanation:

- I've used named groups `(?<groupName>regex)` but they aren't necessary and could just be `()`'s - either way, the sub-captures will still be available as 1,2,and 3. Also note the `(?:regex)` constructs that are for grouping *only* and do not "remember" anything, and won't mess up your captures)
- `(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?)|(?:\.\d+))` **first number**: either leading digit(s) followed optionally by a decimal point and digit(s), OR a leading decimal point followed by digit(s)
- `\s*` zero or more spaces in between
- `[+\/*-]` **operator**: character class meaning a plus, division sign, minus, or multiply.
- `\s*` zero or more spaces in between
- `(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?)|(?:\.\d+)` **second number**: same pattern as first number.

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tF4nI5/2) output:

[image]

Comment: I ran `/(?<operand1>(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?)|(?:\.\d+))(?<operator>[+\/*-])(?<operand2>(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?)|(?:\.\d+))/.match('1+23.7').to_a` and I got 
`=> ["1+23.7", "1", "+", "23.7"]` I think this solution is the closest thing I can get. But what I really want is the 1..3 index of that array. Do you know how to do that? Thanks a bunch.

Comment: I updated with a more detailed explanation. as far as the match object results, the first element is always the *whole match*. slice off the first element in this case: `myMatchArray.shift`

Comment: ***Please use the `x` flag for long regular expressions. It makes them a hell of a lot easier to parse (for humans) when there are comments explaining what part matches what.*** If you don't know what the `x` flag is, _look it up_. It will help you with so many things.

Answer (score 2):

I arrived a little late to this party, and found that many of the good answers had already been taken.  So, I set out to expand on the theme slightly and compare the performance and robustness of each of the solutions.  It seemed like a fun way to entertain myself this morning.

In addition to the 3 examples given in the question, I added test cases for each of the four operators, as well as for some new edge cases.  These edge cases included handling of negative numbers and arbitrary spaces between operands, as well as how each of the algorithms handled expected failures.

The answers revolved around 3 methods: `split`, `scan`, and `match`.  I also wrote new solutions using each of these 3 methods, specifically respecting the additional edge cases that I added to here.  I ran all of the algorithms against this full set of test cases, and ended up with a table of pass/fail results.

Next, I created a benchmark that created 1,000,000 test strings that each of the solutions would be able to parse properly, and ran each solution against that sample set.

On first benchmarking, Cary Swoveland's solution performed far better than the others, but didn't pass the added test cases.  I made very minor changes to his solution to produce a solution that supported both negative numbers and arbitrary spaces, and included that test as `Swoveland+`.

The final results printed from to the console are here (note: horizontal scroll to see all results):

```
| Test Case |  match  |  match  |  scan   |  scan   |partition|  split  |  split  |   split  |  split  |
|           | Gaskill | sweaver | Gaskill | techbio |Swoveland| Gaskill |Swoveland|Swoveland+|  Lilue  |
|------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| "1+12"    |  Pass   |  Pass   |  Pass   |  Pass   |  Pass   |  Pass   |  Pass   |   Pass   |  Pass   |
| "6/0.25"  |  Pass   |  Pass   |  Pass   |  Pass   |  Pass   |  Pass   |  Pass   |   Pass   |  Pass   |
| "3/0.125" |  Pass   |  Pass   |  Pass   |  Pass   |  Pass   |  Pass   |  Pass   |   Pass   |  Pass   |
| "30-6"    |  Pass   |  Pass   |  Pass   |  Pass   |  Pass   |  Pass   |  Pass   |   Pass   |  Pass   |
| "3*8"     |  Pass   |  Pass   |  Pass   |  Pass   |  Pass   |  Pass   |  Pass   |   Pass   |  Pass   |
| "20--4"   |  Pass   |   --    |  Pass   |   --    |  Pass   |  Pass   |   --    |   Pass   |  Pass   |
| "33+-9"   |  Pass   |   --    |  Pass   |   --    |  Pass   |  Pass   |   --    |   Pass   |  Pass   |
| "-12*-2"  |  Pass   |   --    |  Pass   |   --    |  Pass   |  Pass   |   --    |   Pass   |  Pass   |
| "-72/-3"  |  Pass   |   --    |  Pass   |   --    |  Pass   |  Pass   |   --    |   Pass   |  Pass   |
| "34 - 10" |  Pass   |  Pass   |  Pass   |  Pass   |  Pass   |  Pass   |  Pass   |   Pass   |  Pass   |
| " 15+ 9"  |  Pass   |  Pass   |  Pass   |  Pass   |  Pass   |  Pass   |  Pass   |   Pass   |  Pass   |
| "4*6 "    |  Pass   |  Pass   |  Pass   |  Pass   |  Pass   |  Pass   |  Pass   |   Pass   |  Pass   |
| "b+0.5"   |  Pass   |  Pass   |  Pass   |   --    |   --    |   --    |   --    |    --    |   --    |
| "8---0.5" |  Pass   |  Pass   |  Pass   |   --    |   --    |   --    |   --    |    --    |   --    |
| "8+6+10"  |  Pass   |   --    |  Pass   |   --    |   --    |   --    |   --    |    --    |   --    |
| "15*x"    |  Pass   |  Pass   |  Pass   |   --    |   --    |   --    |   --    |    --    |   --    |
| "1.A^ff"  |  Pass   |  Pass   |  Pass   |   --    |   --    |   --    |   --    |    --    |   --    |


ruby 2.2.5p319 (2016-04-26 revision 54774) [x86_64-darwin14]
============================================================
                                user     system      total        real
match (Gaskill):            4.770000   0.090000   4.860000 (  5.214996)
match (sweaver2112):        4.640000   0.040000   4.680000 (  4.911849)
scan (Gaskill):             7.360000   0.080000   7.440000 (  7.719646)
scan (techbio):            12.930000   0.140000  13.070000 ( 13.791613)
partition (Swoveland):      5.390000   0.050000   5.440000 (  5.648762)
split (Gaskill):            5.150000   0.100000   5.250000 (  5.455094)
split (Swoveland):          3.860000   0.060000   3.920000 (  4.040774)
split (Swoveland+):         4.240000   0.040000   4.280000 (  4.537570)
split (Lilue):              7.540000   0.090000   7.630000 (  8.022252)
```

In order to keep this post from being far too long, I've included the complete code for this test at https://gist.github.com/mgaskill/96f04e7e1f72a86446f4939ac690759a

The robustness test cases can be found in the first table above.  The `Swoveland+` solution is:

```
f,op,l = formula.split(/\b\s*([+\/*-])\s*/)
return [f.to_f, op, l.to_f]
```

This includes a `\b` metacharacter prior to splitting on an operator ensures that the previous character is a word character, giving support for negative numbers in the second operand.  The `\s*` metacharacter expressions support arbitrary spaces between operands and operator.  These changes incur less than 10% performance overhead for the additional robustness.

The solutions that I provided are here:

```
def match_gaskill(formula)
  return [] unless (match = formula.match(/^\s*(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s*([+\/*-])\s*(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s*$/))
  return [match[1].to_f, match[2], match[3].to_f]
end

def scan_gaskill(formula)
  return [] unless (match = formula.scan(/^\s*(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s*([+*\/-])\s*(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s*$/))[0]
  return [match[0][0].to_f, match[0][1], match[0][2].to_f]
end

def split_gaskill(formula)
  match = formula.split(/(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s*([+\/*-])\s*(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)/)
  return [match[1].to_f, match[2], match[3].to_f]
end
```

The `match` and `scan` solutions are very similar, but perform significantly differently, which is very interesting, because they use the exact same regex to do the work.  The `split` solution is slightly simpler, and only splits on the entire expression, capturing each operand and the operator, separately.

Note that none of the `split` solutions was able to properly identify failures.  Adding this support requires additional parsing of the operands, which significantly increases the overhead of the solution, typically running about 3 times slower.

For both performance and robustness, `match` is the clear winner.  If robustness isn't a concern, but performance is, use `split`.  On the other hand, `scan` provided complete robustness, but was more than 50% slower than the equivalent `match` solution.

Also note that using an efficient way to extract the results from the solution into the result array is as important to performance as is the algorithm chosen.  The technique of capturing the results array into multiple variables (used in `Woveland`) outperformed the `map` solutions dramatically.  Early testing showed that the `map` extraction solution more than doubled the runtimes of even the highest-performing solutions, hence the exceptionally high runtime numbers for `Lilue`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Your solution is the performance winner in my benchmark breakdown!

Comment: You are to be commended for your excellent work, which obviously consumed a considerable amount of time. Since you posted this I changed my answer twice, once to deal with negative numbers, and then to use `partition` rather than `split`, and a different regex. (I didn't see your answer until now.) Could you add my latest method to the benchmark?

Comment: @CarySwoveland Absolutely, I will add your update and republish.  I was hoping for exactly that outcome!  I did this testing and benchmark out of personal curiosity, and the results were interesting enough that I thought I'd share.  I'd like to keep it live to come up with a true "best" solution, so thank you for helping do that very thing.

Answer (score 1):

```
R = /
    (?<=\d) # match a digit in a positive lookbehind
    [^\d\.] # match any character other than a digit or period
    /x      # free-spacing regex definition mode

def split_it(str)
  f,op,l = str.delete(' ').partition(R)
  [convert(f), op, convert(l)]
end

def convert(str)
  (str =~ /\./) ? str.to_f : str.to_i
end

split_it "1+12"
  #=> [1, "+", 12] 
split_it "3/ 5.2"
  #=> [3, "/", 5.2] 
split_it "-4.1 * 6"
  #=> [-4.1, "*", 6] 
split_it "-8/-2"
  #=> [-8, "/", -2]
```

The regex can of course be written in the conventional way:

```
R = /(?<=\d)[^\d\.]/
```